Can super heavy elements form inside black holes?
I have read that heavy elements like gold and uranium are formed due to extreme pressure, through a process similar to nuclear fission. I wonder if something like atomic no. 500 or 5000 could form inside black holes due to the extreme pressure at the center.
I am not too familiar with physics of black holes, let alone singularities. I am just assuming a black hole to be a region of extreme gravitational density in space.

As I said here: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/32677/16685 we cannot say exactly what happens at the core of a black hole, we need a theory that unites General Relativity and Quantum mechanics to answer such questions. But it's very unlikely that any normal form of matter can survive at the core.

You don’t need a black hole. Things like this already happen in a neutron star.

Theoretically, but good luck getting the atoms to stay together given that the black hole's gravity even has the tidal power to rip atoms apart! That said, if the black hole is rotating, then the effects of tidal stretching (spaghettification) become nonexistent or nearly nonexistent.
